# Mercurial - Multiple heads - how do I "abandon" one head and take the other as tip/default?

Tags: mercurial, dvcs, branching-and-merging, bitbucket

I forked someone elses repository on Bitbucket and made some changes (and pushed them to my forked repo). In the meantime, the original author made substantial changes (pretty much a rewrite).

I want to update my repo to be exactly the same as his (but with my changes still present on that tag) in a way that he can easily pull my new changes without the previous changes I made affecting anything.

I pulled his changes into my local version, which left me with 2 heads. I want to just take his head as the tip/default. I tried to resolve this (based on some SO answers) by doing:

```
hg update -r [myrev]
hg commit --close-branch
hg update -r [hisrev]
```

This *seemed* to put me in a state I wanted. My working directory looks like his. However, when I tryed to `hg push` I'm told this will create multiple remote heads, and I'm not sure if this is what I want (the message makes it sound scary!)

So, have I done this correctly? Should I force the push? Will this do what I want (eg. keep a copy of my changes so I can get to them, but in a way that generally won't interfere?). If so, was this the best way to achieve this?

Comment: are you missing a link on the word "this"?

Comment: Oops, typo. Should've been "his". I went ahead and pushed (`hg push -f`) and it did seem to do exactly what I want. The only complication was that because my "closed" branch (which probably didn't really need to be closed) had the last commit and therefore became tip. I just committing a trivial change to the "open" head and that fixed this.

Comment: Yes, you do need another commit to become the tip. Remember you can always practice a push on a clone of the target repository to see if it will do what you want. You can also use hg outgoing to see what will be pushed in advance.

Comment: That's a good point - I didn't think of that. I crossed my fingers when pushing, but I think your way is probably  better ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Heads on a closed branch are still heads, so if you want to push those changes you'll need `--force`.

The other option, is to merge that head into what you want to be your default branch, but select none of its changes.  This can be done non-interactively using:

```
hg update [hisrev]
hg --config ui.merge=internal:local merge [myrev]
hg commit
```

You'll be down to one head, and it will have only his content, but yours is still available in the history.

Comment: Thanks - that sounds like what I was trying to do, so handy to know! Though I think in this instance, closing the branch was probably actually more appropriate, since the new merged version didn't contain the functionality from my (the closed) branch